# Cross-platform HTML touchend event handling

Tags: javascript, html, touch, dom-events, multi-touch

In reading about the `touchend` event, it seem that the behavior is somewhat inconsistent across different devices. I simply want to know the best and simplest way to determine whether all touching has ceased. Do I understand correctly that I can't rely on event.touches being null or empty when this is the case because some devices will include the ended touch in that list? Do I understand correctly that I can't rely on `changedTouches` being the same length as touches when this is the case because some devices will exclude the ended touch from touches?

Answer (score 0):

For now only OSX (ipad, iphone) support ongesturechange event on their browser. All the other events are supported in all devices, here are some of them and that is the way how to use them. To detect touch end you can use touchend even, it is the same over all devices and it will fires when all fingers are not in touch:

```
$(someel).bind('touchend',callback');
```

To detect touch support just use this

```
var touchy=("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)?true:false;
```

Safari developers ipad guide has a good documentation on this.

UPDATE: In fact I was wrong, touchend fires every time a finger lifts up: here is an excellent pdf for you: http://www.albanx.com/programing/ajaxupload/uploaded/SafariJSRef.pdf look at page 21.

Comment: What if you have two fingers touching, and then you lift one? Will any device fire touchend under this condition?  I don't want to run my code under this condition; I only want to run my code when *every* finger has been removed.

Comment: No, it will not, the touchend runs when all fingers has been removed. So you are fine. You can even detect the number of touching fingers with the event: fingers=e.touches.length;

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? The fact that touchend doesn't fire until all fingers are removed?

Comment: yes try here http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1 . I had an excellent apple pdf file that explains that but I really cant find it right now

Comment: The article referenced by your "UPDATE" is interesting, but still doesn't explain a cross-platform mechanism for determining when all fingers are removed does it?  This is specific to iOS.